# C pointer changes after non-assigning addition

Tags: c, pointers, closures, immutability, nested-function

I am trying to understand how closures could be implemented in a language like C.

Currently I want to create an `adder` function that takes an `int`, and returns another function that also takes an `int` param. Invoking the returned function should result in the sum of the two parameters.

Here's the pseudocode example:

```c
fn adder(int lhs) {
    return fn (int rhs) {
        return lhs + rhs
    }
}
```

Since nested functions are not available in standard C, I thought I could implement them by passing states. Here's my C implementation:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct
{
    int *a; // This attribute should be a pointer as in my
            // ideal interpretation of closures, the state of
            // the parent function should be mutable within the child
} ClosureState;

int adder_inner(ClosureState state, int b)
{
    printf("a = %d\n", *state.a);
    return *state.a + b;
}

ClosureState make_adder(int a)
{
    ClosureState state = {
        .a = &a};

    return state;
}

int main()
{
    ClosureState adder_state = make_adder(5);
    int res1 = adder_inner(adder_state, 5);
    int res2 = adder_inner(adder_state, 10);
    int res3 = adder_inner(adder_state, 50);

    printf("%d, %d, %d\n", res1, res2, res3);
    return 0;
}
```

The problem: The `adder_state` object seems to be modified after every invocation of `adder_inner` but I don't understand why as `*state.a` is never reassigned.

The output of the code above is:

```
$ clang -o clj clj.c && ./clj
a = 5
a = 10
a = 50
10, 20, 100
```

Comment: The argument variable `a` in the `make_adder` function is a *local* variable. Once the function returns the life-time of all local variables (including argument variables) ends. All pointers you have to such variables will become invalid, and dereferencing such pointers will lead to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: That's it, thank you! Mind posting it as an answer?

Comment: As an aside, what you are discussing is a 'closure', not a 'clojure'. Clojure is the name of a programming language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no reason for `ClojureState` (`ClosureState`) to hold a pointer. It will be much easier if it just holds the `int` itself:

````
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct
{
    int a; // No need for a pointer, the value can still be
           // changed in adder_inner() if needed.
} ClosureState;

int adder_inner(ClosureState *state, int b)
{
    printf("a = %d\n", state->a);
    return state->a + b;
}

ClosureState make_adder(int a)
{
    ClosureState state = {
        .a = a};

    return state;
}

int main()
{
    ClosureState adder_state = make_adder(5);
    int res1 = adder_inner(&adder_state, 5);
    int res2 = adder_inner(&adder_state, 10);
    int res3 = adder_inner(&adder_state, 50);

    printf("%d, %d, %d\n", res1, res2, res3);
    return 0;
}```
````